# datatables.net codeigniter not sorting when query have order_by

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

i have used this datatable.net datatables, the problem is when i click sort it does not work when i have `order_by` in query

here is my model

```
var $table = 'attendance';
var $column = array('DATE','TIME_IN','BREAK_OUT','BREAK_IN','TIME_OUT','TOTAL_TIME','STATUS');
var $order = array('DATE' => 'asc');

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

private function _get_datatables_query()
{

    $this->db->where('ID_NUM', $_SESSION['EMP_ID']->ID_NUM);
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->order_by('DATE','desc')


    $i = 0;

    foreach ($this->column as $item) 
    {
        if($_POST['search']['value'])
            ($i===0) ? $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']) : $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
        $column[$i] = $item;
        $i++;

    }

    if(isset($_POST['order']))
    {
        $this->db->order_by($column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);

    } 
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }

}
```

everything works perfectly fine except for the sorting..

Answer (score 0):

Most data-tables always have their own sorting mechanism inbuilt. That's why the order by clause looks like its not working but it is.You should be able to sort the table when you click on the heading of the column.

Comment: and do you have any idea how this data tables of datatables.net works? please tell me if you do. thanks

Comment: For datatables.net you will have to import its own css and jquery files. Depending on the table you choose to use (They have different tables types) sorting is always implemented in the imported file. They are very easy to use. Just read their documentation well